# How to store or display the selenium commands log after the execution of testcases

Tags: java, selenium, automation, logging

I am running the selenium testcases using java.

I wanted to store/display the log generated after executing the selenium commands.

I tried the approach given here: [from selenium test scripts back to selenese](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299159/from-selenium-test-scripts-back-to-selenese). But i was unable to override the Httpcommandprocessor's docommand() method. Need suggestions/code for this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the **getLog** Selenium command:
http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/seleniumhq/selenium/selenium/2.0a2/selenium-2.0a2-javadoc.jar!/com/thoughtworks/selenium/DefaultSelenium.html#getLog()

Comment: Any example of how to implement the getLog() method.